# Passing argument through webservice as null

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm new with the .net webservices and had some problem with them.
I've got some wsdl file with specification of this webservice and generete proxy class using **wsdl.exe**. Then by using this class sending some data and here is a problem.
Proxy class has some not nullable type such **DateTime**. 
So I cannot do something like this:

```
someDateField = null;
```

So I'm only setting

```
someDateFieldSpecified = false;
```

And this don't working like I think. I dont want to send this fields through web by some magic mechanizm adding it to xml with my program produce.

```
...
<someDateField>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</someDateField>
...
```

Is any way to don't send this fields? I read some about create custom serializer but on my level of knowledge is quite difficult task for me.

Comment: Have you tried using `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime`?

Comment: Yeap it works. I had made wrong assumptions, If i would change something in proxy class that I would had problem with contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime` is not a nullable type so it can't accept `null` as a value. However, `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>` can accept nulls and should solve your problem.

Setting the `someDateFieldSpecified` proprerty to `false` will simply omit the `someDateField` field from your request, but it would be up to the server to determine how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the someDateFieldSpecified proprerty to false  will simply omit the someDateField field from your request, but it would be up to the server to determine how to handle that.